# Is there an alternate to WebBrowser for windows forms?

Tags: .net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'd like to know if there is an alternate to the WebBrowser control for a .net Windows Forms application? I've suffered through one issue where a system changed to a newer version of IE and my application's HTML editor broke - the app started crashing. I'd be willing to pay for a commercial product if I can get better stability.

Comment: Did you determine why your HTML editor broke? Did IE actually break something in the public interface?

Comment: @John - the customer let windows update install IE9. Then my app started crashing due to the browser control. Downgraded to IE8 and the problem went away. And, no, I did not determine a reason. And it's almost impossible to get the customer to help with debugging. I added a DocumentCompleted handler that might have helped. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021527/winforms-problem-with-mshtml-and-ie9

Comment: Part of my fix for IE9 not allowing editing was to add ((HTMLBody)_doc.body).contentEditable = "true"; so something in the interface is different. But this still doesn't fix the customer's issue. Even asking them to reinstall IE9 as a test is difficult.

Comment: @John - I didn't get the hang condition the customer had. But I did have to edit my code to get the editor function working again as I recall. This was a few months ago. It's a research project I want to avoid in future. I think the customer's problem would go away with a reinstall of IE9.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look to [HTMLRenderer](https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com/) on CodePlex:

> The rich formatting power of HTML in your .NET applications using
>   simple controls or static rendering code. The library is 100% managed
>   C# code without any external dependencies (no WebBrowser control,
>   ActiveX / COM or MSHTML dll), the only requirement is .NET 2.0 or
>   higher.

This is just... badass.

Answer (score 2):

There is webkit dot net -- a wrapper over web kit. http://webkitdotnet.sourceforge.net/

More alternatives are listed here: [vb 2008 webbrowser alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692221/vb-2008-webbrowser-alternative/5692272#5692272)